# How to delete a row from a 2D list based on specific column values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

For example we have this 2D list:

```
list1 = [['tom',67,'engineer',2],
     ['ron',42,'scientist',4],
      ['alie',56,'doctor',3],
      ['rambo',29,'lawyer',7]]
```

Now I have to delete rows in which column 4 has odd values. Is there any way in python3 to do this using `pop` or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way it to create a new list from `list1`.  You can assign this to `list1` if you wish to replace it.  You can use:

```
list2 = [v for v in list1 if v[3] % 2 == 0]
```

In your example, `list2` gets the following value:

```
[['tom', 67, 'engineer', 2],
 ['ron', 42, 'scientist', 4]]
```

If you just want to replace `list1` with the new list, you can do so directly:

```
list1 = [v for v in list1 if v[3] % 2 == 0]
```

If you need to preserve references to `list1`, you can change the existing list with:

```
list1[:] = [v for v in list1 if v[3] % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: See my edit.  The bottom line shows how to destructively modify `list1` to contain the filtered list.  Any existing references to `list1` will pick up the changes.

Comment: sir what does preserve references mean here?

Comment: That's what you were asking for.  You want to modify `list1`, rather than assign a new value to it.  The difference is that if you do `x = list1` before performing the update, then `x` will reflect those changes if you destructively modify `list1`.  If you just assign to `list1`, then `x` will retain the old value.

Comment: hello sir can i use something like if v[2] == 'scientist' and v[3] %2==0 in here?

Comment: Yes, you can use an expression you like for that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with using `remove`. It's easy to understand you.

```
for value in list1[:]:
    if value[3] % 2 != 0:
        list1.remove(value)
```

**Result**

```
[['tom', 67, 'engineer', 2], ['ron', 42, 'scientist', 4]]
```